# What's the easiest way to load single band Landsat 8 rasters from AWS and combine them into a single multiband RDD?

Tags: landsat, geotrellis

I'm using [geotrellis](https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis) to load geotiff rasters from Landsat 8 that are sitting on [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/landsat/). However, they are stored on a per-band basis. I can use `S3GeoTiff` class to load individual bands, e.g.:

```
val options = S3GeoTiffRDD.Options(getS3Client = () => S3Client.ANONYMOUS)

val rddBlue = S3GeoTiffRDD.spatial("landsat-pds", "L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/LC81390452014295LGN00_B2.TIF", options)
val rddGreen = S3GeoTiffRDD.spatial("landsat-pds", "L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/LC81390452014295LGN00_B3.TIF", options)
val rddRed = S3GeoTiffRDD.spatial("landsat-pds", "L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/LC81390452014295LGN00_B4.TIF", options)
```

But how do I go about combining them to generate an RGB raster, e.g.

```
val rddRGB = ??? // something like combineRDDs(rddRed, rddGreen, rddBlue)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the RDDs of single files with no `maxTileSize` option set, you'll end up with RDDs of full images (one element). I'd recommend setting the [maxTileSize option](https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/blob/1.1/s3/src/main/scala/geotrellis/spark/io/s3/S3GeoTiffRDD.scala#L50-L52).

There's an overload that allows you to [place extra information into the key](https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/blob/1.1/s3/src/main/scala/geotrellis/spark/io/s3/S3GeoTiffRDD.scala#L100). This is how I'd approach this problem generically.

Here is some code that does what you are looking for, which utilizes those options:

```scala
import geotrellis.raster._
import geotrellis.spark._
import geotrellis.spark.io.s3._
import geotrellis.vector._

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd._

import java.net.URI
import scala.math.BigDecimal.RoundingMode

implicit val sc: SparkContext =
  geotrellis.spark.util.SparkUtils.createLocalSparkContext("local[*]", "landsat-example")

try {

  val options =
    S3GeoTiffRDD.Options(
      getS3Client = () => S3Client.ANONYMOUS,
      maxTileSize = Some(512),
      numPartitions = Some(100)
    )

  type LandsatKey = (ProjectedExtent, URI, Int)

  // For each RDD, we're going to include more information in the key, including:
  // - the ProjectedExtent
  // - the URI
  // - the future band value
  def uriToKey(bandIndex: Int): (URI, ProjectedExtent) => LandsatKey =
    { (uri, pe) =>
      (pe, uri, bandIndex)
    }

  // Read an RDD of source tiles for each of the bands.

  val redSourceTiles =
    S3GeoTiffRDD[ProjectedExtent, LandsatKey, Tile](
      "landsat-pds",
      "L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/LC81390452014295LGN00_B2.TIF",
      uriToKey(0),
      options
    )

  val greenSourceTiles =
    S3GeoTiffRDD[ProjectedExtent, LandsatKey, Tile](
      "landsat-pds",
      "L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/LC81390452014295LGN00_B3.TIF",
      uriToKey(1),
      options
    )

  val blueSourceTiles =
    S3GeoTiffRDD[ProjectedExtent, LandsatKey, Tile](
      "landsat-pds",
      "L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/LC81390452014295LGN00_B4.TIF",
      uriToKey(2),
      options
    )

  // Union these together, rearrange the elements so that we'll be able to group by key,
  // group them by key, and the rearrange again to produce multiband tiles.
  val sourceTiles: RDD[(ProjectedExtent, MultibandTile)] = {
    sc.union(redSourceTiles, greenSourceTiles, blueSourceTiles)
      .map { case ((pe, uri, bandIndex), tile) =>
        // Get the center of the tile, which we will join on
        val (x, y) = (pe.extent.center.x, pe.extent.center.y)

        // Round the center coordinates in case there's any floating point errors
        val center =
          (
            BigDecimal(x).setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue(),
            BigDecimal(y).setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
          )

        // Get the scene ID from the path
        val sceneId = uri.getPath.split('/').reverse.drop(1).head

        val newKey = (sceneId, center)
        val newValue = (pe, bandIndex, tile)
        (newKey, newValue)
      }
      .groupByKey()
      .map { case (oldKey, groupedValues) =>
        val projectedExtent = groupedValues.head._1
        val bands = Array.ofDim[Tile](groupedValues.size)
        for((_, bandIndex, tile) <- groupedValues) {
          bands(bandIndex) = tile
        }

        (projectedExtent, MultibandTile(bands))
      }
  }

  // From here, you could ingest the multiband layer.
  // But for a simple test, we will rescale the bands and write them out to a single GeoTiff
  import geotrellis.spark.tiling.FloatingLayoutScheme
  import geotrellis.raster.io.geotiff.GeoTiff

  val (_, metadata) = sourceTiles.collectMetadata[SpatialKey](FloatingLayoutScheme(512))
  val tiles = sourceTiles.tileToLayout[SpatialKey](metadata)
  val raster =
    ContextRDD(tiles, metadata)
      .withContext { rdd =>
        rdd.mapValues { tile =>
          // Magic numbers! These were created by fiddling around with
          // numbers until some example landsat images looked good enough
          // to put on a map for some other project.
          val (min, max) = (4000, 15176)
          def clamp(z: Int) = {
            if(isData(z)) { if(z > max) { max } else if(z < min) { min } else { z } }
            else { z }
          }
          val red = tile.band(0).map(clamp _).delayedConversion(ByteCellType).normalize(min, max, 0, 255)
          val green = tile.band(1).map(clamp _).delayedConversion(ByteCellType).normalize(min, max, 0, 255)
          val blue = tile.band(2).map(clamp _).delayedConversion(ByteCellType).normalize(min, max, 0, 255)

          MultibandTile(red, green, blue)
        }
      }
      .stitch

  GeoTiff(raster, metadata.crs).write("/tmp/landsat-test.tif")
} finally {
  sc.stop()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to change `val newKey = (uri, center)` to `val newKey = center` (otherwise it wouldn't group tiles since uri is unique for each band), but after that, it worked. 

But do you mind elaborating a bit more on the magic numbers you used? Where do they come from? Thanks!

Comment: @dff The magic numbers come from another project, which you can find here: (https://github.com/geotrellis/geotrellis-landsat-emr-demo/blob/master/server/src/main/scala/demo/Render.scala#L19). Also I made a few fixes and set this example into repo as seen in this PR: https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/pull/2233 Thank you for the question!